# Rewrite URL using .htaccess with a static query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite a url to static query as:

`example.com/register => example.com/login.php?page=register`

I'm using this:

`RewriteRule ^register login.php?page=register [NC,L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(register)/?$ /login.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: this line is creating problem :- RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/?$ profile.php?profileId=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: nope not working, i have this thing. xxx.com/213 or xxx.com/UserName to read profiles so xxx.com/register is passed by the profile reading Rule RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/?$ profile.php?profileId=$1 [NC,L] If in any way, we could bypass this rule only for xxx.com/register then ur line would work. As when i comment the above profile rule then ur line works smooth

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(register)$ login.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^register$ login.php?page=register [NC,QSA,L]
```